# Degree of a divisor on surfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm reading surfaces from ALgebraic Geometry of Robin Hartshorne. On chapter $5$ page $357$ there is an affirmation: "A divisor on a surface is a sum of curves, so (in the absence of a projective embedding) it does not make sense to talk about the degree of a divisor, as in the case of curves."

Why is that? The degree would be the formal sum of the coefficients of the divisor, so those numbers will only exist if there is a projective embedding?

Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: Could you explain how you define the multiplicity of the zero of a meromorphic function on $\mathbb{C}/(\mathbb{Z}+i\mathbb{Z}) \times \mathbb{C}/(\mathbb{Z}+i\mathbb{Z})$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define the degree of a divisor as the sum of the coefficients, but that is not a useful notion —in other words, it does not have the properties we want the degree to have.

The problem is that what you really need is not on take into account the coefficients but also, somehow, the 'degree' of the components of the divisor themselves, and that is not well defined.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still have the doubt if it is defined if there is a projective embedding? why?

Comment: If you have a projective embedding, you have a fixed ample divisor with which to intersect divisors. For example, on $\mathbb P^2$ you can take a line as an ample divisor, and so the degree of a plane curve is its degree as a divisor.

Answer (score 3):

The degree of a curve is not well-defined. For example, both line and smooth conics are isomorphic $\Bbb P^1$. In fact, the Veronese embedding $v_d : \Bbb P^1 \to \Bbb P^d$ shows that for any integer $d$, there is a curve $C_d \subset \Bbb P^d$ isomorphic to $\Bbb P^1$ and of degree $d$.